# How to automatically launch android Acess Point on startup?

Tags: automation, wifi-tethering, auto-start

My Galaxy S with the Samsung Android built on it offers me the option the run the phone as a W-LAN acess point that connects to the internet via mobile data.

I would like to configure  the access point to start working immediately after booting the phone.

How to do that?

Bonus points if the setting can be achieved via adb and/or if I can set the wifi-password from adb as well.

Comment: For readers: User Axel in a link-only answer reported this link: [How to auto start Wifi hotspot on Android 4.4.4](http://www.beer.org/blog/index.php/2014/10/24/how-to-auto-start-wifi-hotspot-on-android-4-4-4/)? Seems useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WiFi password IMHO is only setup once, when you configure your device's hotspot. Lateron, you simply activate/deactivate it.

To automate the latter, you could e.g. use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm):

**Profile "AutoHotspot"**:

- **Condition:** "Device Boot"
- **Task:** "WiFi Tether" → set On

With this profile activated, your Hotspot would be automatically be enabled as soon as the device has completed booting up.

For the "bonus point" you mentioned: There's a free 7-day trial available on the [Tasker Homepage](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/). You can download the `.apk` to your computer, and use ADB to install it on your device (`adb pm install`)...

Comment: Thanks, that is already helpful. The "bonuspoint" was about if there is a way to do the whole setup from adb. In the context of your answer, that would mean installing tasker, setting the profile, and configuring the wify password. Imagine a phone screen that is broken or unresponsive.

Comment: I understood that -- was just "playing with words" here. I'm not sure whether that's fully doable via ADB -- even if you prepare the `.xml` for the profile and `adb push` it to the device, I have no idea whether *Tasker* offers an intent you could invoke to import the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the bonus points and starting via adb on a device with broken screen, I think Herb Peyerl found a good solution here:
[Auto start hotspot on Android 4.4.4](http://www.beer.org/blog/index.php/2014/10/24/how-to-auto-start-wifi-hotspot-on-android-4-4-4/)